# Zero Disk Space

Tags: linux, ext4, dd, disk

I have a **Centos 7** server with `ext4` running as a `KVM` and I want to zero the free disk space.  This is so when I backup the KVM the compressed image size is reduced.  I saw this command etc.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/zero bs=64k; sync; sync; sync; rm -f /zero
```

Is there anyway to make this stop when "/" root is 98 percent full?

Comment: Do you have reserved-for-root inodes/blocks set up for the device (often: 10%), and would you be happy if filled to 100%-10%=90%?

Comment: I am most concerned of the moment disk space is exhausted that some other processes will not be able to write to disk and crash etc.

Comment: Looking at df -k and wanting to know how to get numerical value of percentage of /tmp used in bash script to compare too.